# Custom Errors for RegexParsers

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

May someone help me understand the following behavior:
`parseAll (parseIf, "If bla blablaa")` should result in `is expected`. Instead I always get `string matching regex 'is\b' expected but 'b' found`.
I guess it has something to do with whitespaces because `"   If bla is blablaa"` (notice the whitespaces at the beginning) results in the same behavior. I tried it with StandardTokenParsers and everything worked fine. But STP unfortunately doesn't support regex.
Follow-up question: How would I have to alter RegexParsers so it uses a sequence of Strings instead of a sequence of chars? That would make error reporting a lot more easy.

```
lazy val parseIf = roleGiverIf ~ giverRole

lazy val roleGiverIf =
  kwIf ~> identifier | failure("""A rule must begin with if""")
lazy val giverRole =
  kwIs ~> identifier | failure("""is expected""")

lazy val keyword =
  kwIf | kwAnd | kwThen | kwOf | kwIs | kwFrom | kwTo

lazy val identifier =
  not(keyword) ~ roleEntityLiteral
// ...

def roleEntityLiteral: Parser[String] =
  """([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]|\\[\\/bfnrt]|\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})\S*""".r 
def kwIf: Parser[String] = "If\\b".r
def kwIs: Parser[String] = "is\\b".r

// ...

parseAll(parseIf, "If bla blablaa") match {
  case Success(parseIf, _) => println(parseIf)
  case Failure(msg, _) => println("Failure: " + msg)
  case Error(msg, _) => println("Error: " + msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is very weird. When you call `|` and both sides are failures, the side where the failure happened *last* is selected, ties favoring the left-sided one.

When you try to parse directly with `giverRole`, it produces the result you expect. If you add a successful match before the failure, though, it produces the result you are seeing.

The reason is rather subtle -- I only found it out by sprinkling `log` statements on all parsers. To understand it, you must understand *how does `RegexParser` skip spaces*. Specifically, spaces are skipped *on `accept`*. Because `failure` doesn't call `accept`, it doesn't skip spaces.

While the failure of `kwIs` happens on `b`, as the space as skipped, the failure of `failure` happens *on the space after `If`*. Here:

```
If bla blablaa
   ^ kwIs fails here
  ^ failure fails here
```

Therefore, the error message on `kwIs` gets precedence by the rule I mentioned.

You can get around this problem by making the parser skip the spaces without matching anything. It is important that this pattern always match, or you'll get an even more confusing error message. Here's a suggestion I think works:

```
"\\b|$".r ~ failure("is expected")
```

Another solution is to use `acceptIf` or `acceptMatch` instead of using the implicit regex accept, in which case you can provide a tailored error message.

Comment: I have written a parser with regex and lexical ability and used acceptIf as you suggest. But it's still strange that the example above won't work as expected. Thanks for your help

Comment: @awertos I finally found out what the problem was. The first solution was more appropriate than I thought -- I just changed it to make the error appear at the proper place, by not consuming any non-space characters.